# asyncio Event/Condition not working with aiohttp?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

The following is a reduced version of server that periodically serves any connected clients with telemetry in the form of json strings. This was my initial attempt, in which the *main* loop pushes data to all connected clients. However, I cannot simply let the handler terminate after "registering" the client. The connection will be closed. So I need to block the handler until the main loop determines the client has disconnected. Signalling the handler through an Event simply does nothing.

```
@routes.get('/telemetry/json')
async def handler(request: Request):
    global CLIENT
    CLIENT = await StreamResponse().prepare(request)
    log.debug(f"Wait for {EVENT}")
    await EVENT.wait()  # This never wakes up!
    log.debug(f"Client {request.remote} disconnected")


async def main():
    global EVENT
    EVENT = Event()
    app = web.Application()
    app.add_routes(routes)
    runner = web.AppRunner(app)
    await runner.setup()
    await web.TCPSite(runner, port=8080).start()
    while True:
        await sleep(1)
        if CLIENT is None:
            continue
        try:
            await CLIENT.write('FLUSH\n'.encode('utf-8'))
            await CLIENT.drain()
        except ConnectionResetError:
            log.debug(f"Notify {EVENT}")
            EVENT.set()


log.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
log.setLevel(10)
asyncio.run(main())
```

To clarify: The use of *global* CLIENT and EVENT is not how it is intended. The handling of multipple clients was removed to make the example code as short as possible.

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense. For a GET the client (and aiohttp handler) expects a web.Response (see https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_quickstart.html#run-a-simple-web-server). Treating this like a 2-way socket and sending a FLUSH doesn't exist for a GET. In addition you have a singular ```global CLIENT``` which breaks aiohttp's view that it will create a new handler as needed for each GET. The simplest way to periodically serve json is with the client polling. Alternatively use a web socket.

Comment: It seems legit to do a `StreamResponse`(!). The use of `global CLIENT` was only to simplify the code to the bare necessities to demonstrate the problem. The real code keeps them in a list.

This is btw for a legacy client. So using HTTP GET to set up the connection is beyond my control.